# Modify audio data (PCM) output and then play in Qt framework

Tags: qt, multimedia, pcm, phonon

I want to load to video file (ex:mpg), and modify the PCM data of the video by a 3rd library then play. 
First, I had tried the Phonon module, and found that it's a high level API so that it can not modify the PCM data. 
Then, I tried to survey the QtMultimedia documents, but I could not find any example to play mpg file. The official site just provide an example using QImage to play a gif file as video.
Any hints is appreciated!

Comment: For which codecs do you want to do that?

Comment: I have not searched the proper 3rd library codecs to decode the video files yet. But, is there any example of connecting codecs and QtMultimedia?

Comment: Yes, and that's a lot of work. When you say PCm, you are speaking about audio only or you mean raw data (audio/video)? How much time do you have at your disposition??

Comment: It's about audio only. I wanna use SoundTouch to apply pitch shifting on the audio data. What I want to design is a Karaoke system. It is just for fun, but harder than I thought. Maybe I'll survey the FFmpeg first.

Comment: take a look at (the spectrum demo)[http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2010/05/18/qtmultimedia-in-action-a-spectrum-analyser/] and tell me what you think

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It looks very complex. I have completed most of the works with Phonon, except for the pitch shifting. It seems like I have to deal with lots of lower level stuff by myself to replace Phonon so that I can apply SoundTouch to do pitch shifting... Thanks anyway!